# create a tar.gz of a directory and clean up the directory except a file?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, tar

I would like to know if tar (1.15.1, Linux system) already has something like this before creating a script for it.

I would like to create a `dir.tar.gz` of a given `dir/` that contains a specific `dir/myfile.gz`. I would like the command to do 2 specific things:

1. Preserve `dir/myfile.gz`
2. Delete everything else in `dir/` after the `dir.tar.gz` is complete.

For example:

```
tree -if .
.
./dir
./dir/dir2
./dir/dir2/file3
./dir/file1
./dir/file2
./dir/myfile.gz

2 directories, 4 files
```

I would like the result of the `tar` command to be:

```
tree -if  
.
./dir
./dir/myfile.gz
./dir.tar.gz

1 directory, 2 files
```

I have read about the `--delete` and `--extract` options, but I am not sure how to apply them in one single command. Any ideas?

Comment: I'd go ahead and make a script for it. It's an awfully specific circumstance you're talking about and I doubt tar has anything built in.

Comment: +1 for well illustrated problem definition. Good luck to all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
tar -zcvf dir.tar.gz --exclude="*.gz" ./dir/. && find ./dir/. ! -name "*.gz" -exec rm -rf {} +
```

#### Test:

```
$ tree -if .
.
./dir
./dir/dir2
./dir/dir2/file3
./dir/file1
./dir/file2
./dir/myfile.gz

2 directories, 4 files

$ tar -zcvf dir.tar.gz --exclude="*.gz" ./dir/. && find ./dir/. ! -name "*.gz" -exec rm -rf {} +
./dir/./
./dir/./file1
./dir/./dir2/
./dir/./dir2/file3
./dir/./file2
rm: cannot remove `.' or `..'

$ tree -if .
.
./dir
./dir/myfile.gz
./dir.tar.gz

1 directory, 2 files
```

Answer (score 1):

You may also be interested in [tardy](http://tardy.sourceforge.net/) which is a tar post-processor (filter), so you can operate (even on the fly) on your tar archive and remove the offending file.